# How to integrate wysiwyg editor with django flatpages?

Tags: django

How to integrate wysiwyg editor with django flatpages? I tryed django-ckeditor but it is not well described by. Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 11):

I just connect django-ckeditor to flatpages application by following code in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.db import models

from cked.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class FlatPageCustom(FlatPageAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': CKEditorWidget}
    }

admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageCustom)
```

It works!

Comment: However it works with the updated version: https://github.com/riklaunim/django-ckeditor
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In which admin.py do I have to add this thing ?

Comment: @Spoutnik16 I used the `admin.py` file of an app that I didn't need to register in the admin console. Works perfectly.

Comment: Your answers got my vote, but i istill look for a way to change the type TextField to RichTextUploadingField.

Comment: CKeditor doesn't look like it's a free product.

Comment: This is all the same a brilliant solution and works just as well with summernote, quill and tinymce. Tried them all and opted for summernote. Slick.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Field
from django.forms import Textarea
from settings import MEDIA_URL

class WidgetWYSIWYG(Textarea):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetWYSIWYG, self).__init__(attrs={'class': 'wysiwygEditor vLargeTextField'}, *args, **kwargs)
    class Media:
        js = (
            MEDIA_URL+'common/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            MEDIA_URL+'common/filebrowser/js/TinyMCEAdmin.js',
            )

class WYSIWYGField(Field):
    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "TextField"

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'widget': WidgetWYSIWYG}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(WYSIWYGField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

in file admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from wysiwyg import WidgetWYSIWYG

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin as FlatPageAdminOld

class FlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdminOld):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': WidgetWYSIWYG},
    }

admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```

Comment: A nice solution but it could do with some more detail really. It's not exactly turnkey. Did you install the media manually, or use django-tinymce? Where is the top file exactly? And where do you drop admin.py. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this application. It's using Tiny MCE.

https://github.com/mjr27/django-flatpages-tinymce

Comment: Not available any more nor working with recent Django versions or maintained.